# how to count observations based on timestamp condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp, pandas-groupby

I have a Pandas dataframe in the following format:

```
id   name    timestamp

001  movie1  2012-05-05  19:52:04
001  movie5  2012-05-05  13:42:52
001  movie3  2012-05-04  18:29:11
002  movie8  2012-05-05  13:18:31
002  movie7  2012-05-04  09:13:28
003  movie7  2012-05-05  19:23:45
003  movie1  2012-05-04  17:00:48
004  movie11 2012-05-05  12:55:34
005  movie8  2012-05-04  15:48:25
005  movie7  2012-05-04  11:14:53
```

with a few thousand rows.

The data shows the movies watched on a video streaming platform. Id is the user id, name is the name of the movie and timestamp is the timestamp at which the movie started.

How can I track if two movies are played consecutively (where consecutively means that the second one is played less than 2 hours from the first one?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: I was trying to use groupby but didn't manage to find a way. I also tried a loop with a new column constructed iteratively based on the condition but would be very inefficient I guess.

Comment: could you clarify how you intend to derive the duration of a session? I mean, if you just know that a movie was *started*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this, sort by user id and date, group by the user id, and find diff in hours:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df.sort_values(by=['id', 'timestamp'], inplace=True)
df['time_diff'] = df.groupby(by=['id'])['timestamp'].diff().astype('timedelta64[h]')
df['<2'] = df['time_diff'] <= 2
print(df)

   id     name                 timestamp  time_diff     <2
2   1   movie3 2009-05-04 18:29:11+00:00        NaN  False
1   1   movie5 2009-05-05 13:42:52+00:00       19.0  False
0   1   movie1 2009-05-05 19:52:04+00:00        6.0  False
4   2   movie7 2009-05-04 09:13:28+00:00        NaN  False
3   2   movie8 2009-05-05 13:18:31+00:00       28.0  False
6   3   movie1 2009-05-04 17:00:48+00:00        NaN  False
5   3   movie7 2009-05-05 19:23:45+00:00       26.0  False
7   4  movie11 2009-05-05 12:55:34+00:00        NaN  False
9   5   movie7 2009-05-04 11:14:53+00:00        NaN  False
8   5   movie8 2009-05-04 15:48:25+00:00        4.0  False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transform it to a date stamp and subtract it
you can use `pd.to_datetime` then subtract the dates and see wich one has the biggest interval